# Why Windows notepad put all the code line on a single line when I open a file created using Notepad++?

Tags: text, editor, notepad++, text-editor, notepad

I have the following problem: I use **Nodepad++** editor to write some text\code and I save my file into it, if later I open this file using the Windows **notepad** this lost the text format and put all the code line on a single line.

Why? Can this thing being a problem?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/362087/notepad-ignoring-linebreaks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CBroe's link: https://superuser.com/questions/362087/notepad-ignoring-linebreaks has a good description of the problem, if the file is in Unix or Mac format it treats line endings differently and Windows Notepad won't recognize them.

In Notepad++ you can change the End-Of-Line encodings through `Edit` > `EOL Conversion` > `Windows Format`, then save the file.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 version 1809 added support for other line endings to Notepad. Up to this point, Notepad only supported CRLF line endings. So any files that used LF endings or another format would show all on one line.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/extended-eol-in-notepad/

Comment: "Today, we’re excited to announce that we have fixed this issue!". Were they trying to fix it all these years? :)